# How to put filter condition on group_concat columns?

Tags: mysql

#### TABLE 1

```
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
|  2 | robin  |
|  3 | jyothi |
|  1 | angel  |
+----+--------+
```

#### TABLE 2

```
+----+---------+--------+
| id | hobbies | ref_id |
+----+---------+--------+
|  1 | walking |      1 |
|  2 | chating |      1 |
|  3 | reading |      2 |
|  4 | walking |      2 |
+----+---------+--------+
```

I want name & their hobbies who have hobby as 'walking' or name is 'robin'

```
+----+-----------------+
| name | hobbies       | 
+----+-----------------+
|  1 | walking,chating |      
|  3 | reading,surfing |    
+----+-----------------+
```

#### used query:

```
select name, group_concat(hobbies) as all_hobbies
from test1,test2
where test1.id = test2.ref_id 
and test1.id in (select ref_id
              from test2
              where hobbies = 'walking')
group by name
```

I don't want to use subquery or save the entire result as virtual table & the search on all_hobbies though where clause. I want to do accomplish the group_concat columns through where clause or some way around as its increasing my SQL_JOIN_SZIE

I cannt use having here as that has to act as or condition for eg:

Either hobbies is 'walking' or name is 'robin'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have mysql installed on this machine, but try this query out, I think it should work. You can think of the `HAVING` clause as a `WHERE` clause for your `GROUP BY`.

```
select name, group_concat(hobbies) as all_hobbies
from test1,test2
where test1.id = test2.ref_id and test1.name = 'robin'
group by name
having all_hobbies like '%walking%'
```

Comment: Your name will give me result for people having hobbies walking but not with name 'robin'. SO, +1 for having

Comment: @Derek, you can use aliases in `having`, but not in `where`, reason being that having is evaluated last, at this point all aliases are known, whereas the `where` clause may be executed when the alias is not yet resolved.

Comment: see edit - you just need to add to the where clause the check for name

Comment: You can also use `having find_in_set('walking',hobbies)`, this will hit just `walking` but reject `dogwalking`.

Answer (score 1):

It can be accomplished by:

```
having all_hobbies like '%walking%' or
name like '%robin%'
```

having caluse will work on group concat colums & normal coumns

Answer (score 0):

I'd join the two tables. Then id select the concatenation using (field a || field b) and place my restriction in the Where clause.